# build web application on 1920x1080 resolution

Tags: frontend, resolution

I'm charged to make a front-end application on 1920x1080 resolution, but my PC is not that wide,so I tried to resize google with inspect in order to make it out, but then I couldn't see my web page properly. So my question is, how to make a web application on a specific resolution like you are doing it normally

Comment: Can't you zoom out your view to 75% or something? How wide is your screen?

Comment: its 1366x768 ..

Comment: If your employee has requested this then ask them for the appropriate resources.

Comment: i am starting work at some company, so that was their task

Comment: I'm in the UK and I would be asking for an appropriate monitor so that I could do my job properly. A decent monitor costs nothing compared to your salary and will help you do your job properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1 - open Inspect,

Step #2 - tap 'Dimensions' on the top (where you see your Width and Height)

Step #3 - Choose 'Edit'

Step #4 - Devices > Add custom device

Step #5 - Choose device name of your choice like 'custom' or something you like, then choose width and height and the last step is to change 'mobile' to 'desktop'

Step #6 - Click 'add' and woalaa

Answer (score -3):

if your screen isn't 1920x1080, you'll cant see what you are doing, but someone with that resolution will see it properly ! You could also use a virtual machine.

Comment: can you be more specific which virtual machine should I use ?

Comment: This should really be a comment

Comment: Also, how would a virtual machine help!